# How to solve differential equations for a system driven by two frequencies ? problem : non-local equations in Laplace space

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, mathematical-physics

When studying the case of a quantum system driven by two different frequencies, I have two solve differential equations of the form

\begin{equation} 
\label{eq1} \dot{a}(t) = \left(\int_0^t f(t-t') \, a(t') \, dt'\right) e^{i Bt}
\end{equation}

with $f(t-t') = e^{i A (t-t')}$.

**I.** When $B = 0$ (case of only one driving) the Laplace transform of the equation yields

$$ s A(s) - a(0) = F(s) \,A(s) $$

thanks to the fact that we have to deal with a convolution product, where $F(s) = 1/(s-iA)$. We then have

$$ A(s) = \frac{a(0)}{s- F(s)}$$

and using the inverse Laplace transform a solution for $a(t)$ can be found.

**II.** When $B \neq 0$ (case of two drivings), the Laplace transform yields

$$ s A(s) - a(0) = F(s-i B) \,A(s-iB) $$

thanks to the fact that the imaginary exponential yields a shift in Laplace space. However, we obtained a non-local equation for $A(s)$.

Question 1 : Is there a method to solve such non-local equation ?

Question 2 : If not, is there then an alternative method to solve the first equation, that is the one in time domain ?

Thank you very much in advance. I think it is quiet a general case of equations we can often encounter.